# Non-standard frequency crystal replacement

Tags: crystal

I'm new to DIY electronics therefore this might well be a noob question.

I'm trying to upcycle a brushless DC motor salvaged from a printer and I accidentally broke a crystal's pin [edit: on the associated driver's circuit].
I tried to find a replacement on the usual RC,Mouser but I don't seem to find the frequency stated on the pcb or the part no printed on the component: XTAL1 4.437M - D437D0C(not sure if the penultimate character is a zero or a letter O)
I guess that it's a 4.437MHz crystal and it might be custom made, be damned patented parts :)

The closest I found are these:

http://au.mouser.com/Passive-Components/Frequency-Control-Timing-Devices/Crystals/_/N-6zu9f?P=1z0wmuu

I don't have a scope and my multimeter cannot measure above a few KHz to test the actual frequency.

My question is whether it's safe/viable to use a crystal with similar frequency or, alternatively, build a frequency multiplier without having a major in physics.

[image]

Comment: In the interest of improved questions in the future: When posting a picture of a part here, crop out things that are not the part, and try to make sure that's what's left is clear enough to actually be of some use. If it's not, try, try again, or change cameras, lighting, etc. In this case, 99+% of it is not the part, and the part is not in focus, as well as being obscured by fingers.

Comment: Sure will do! The pict was only meant to give an idea of the package form factor and dimensions, but I could have cropped it, agreed.

Comment: Brushless motors do not have crystals.  Drivers might, but they won't necessarily be of any use to you unless you have already reverse engineered whatever interface commands them. Most digital logic circuits will be tolerant of small frequency changes, though inferface speeds may change proportionally.  **There is no specific question *usefully* answerable on the basis of knowable facts here**.

Comment: I guess @supercat correctly inferred that the question was about the driver associated with the motor. Those motors rescued from printers are typically found in a motor+driver unit(https://www.google.com.au/search?q=printer+brushless+motor&espv=2&biw=1440&bih=778&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjfn63AmpPOAhWFjJQKHcNNDoAQ_AUIBygC#tbm=isch&q=laser+printer+brushless+motor). My question was merely if, as a rule of thumb, in those kind of drivers, replacing crystals required to find an exact frequency match.

Comment: Also, I said it would be a noob question :)

Comment: The question may be _too_ detailed, but I think it's a reasonable question to ask by a "n00b". I remember when I was one, and I was afraid to change anything at all. Once I had to order a 2N2222 specifically for a circuit because I wasn't sure if I could replace it - these are actually rare in Europe, but you'll find hundreds of BC547 scattered in every junkbin. A more general question would be how important a an exact crystal frequency is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's curious that the last digit is a 7, but the frequency is close enough to a standard PAL subcarrier crystal that I would guess that's probably what it would be.  A standard crystal would be about 762 parts per million lower than 4.437,000Hz, but for a lot of purposes 0.1% accuracy would be adequate.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick reply. I'll give it a go with a standard one.

Comment: You ended on an amalgam of UART 7MHz and PAL 4MHz numbers. Unless I'm missing the point of your answer at 4AM.

Comment: @Asmyldof: Oops.  The frequency is close to the PAL one; I just mistyped the frequency suggested by the original xtal.